# Generate SHA 256 Hash using multiple values in Java/Android

Tags: java, android, hash, sha

I have two objects based on which SHA 256 Hash needs to be generated.

First value is a **JSONObject**
Second value is a **String** variable.

Ideally, what i need is

Hash hash= new Hash(JSONObject, String);

I couldn't find any hash generation methods which takes two values.

Could anyone help me with this?.

Comment: It's up to you to somehow merge those two values, perhaps with a StringBuilder.

Answer (score 1):

SHA 256 works on a byte array as input. You need to convert your JSONObject and your String to byte arrays, then calculate the SHA 256 hash on the concatenation of these byte arrays.

Answer (score 0):

The proper way of generating a sha256 hashcode using key and value

```
   public static String hashMac(String text, String secretKey)
                  throws SignatureException {

                 try {
                  Key sk = new SecretKeySpec(secretKey.getBytes(), HASH_ALGORITHM);
                  Mac mac = Mac.getInstance(sk.getAlgorithm());
                  mac.init(sk);
                  final byte[] hmac = mac.doFinal(text.getBytes());
                  return toHexString(hmac);
                 } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e1) {
                  // throw an exception or pick a different encryption method
                  throw new SignatureException(
                    "error building signature, no such algorithm in device "
                      + HASH_ALGORITHM);
                 } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
                  throw new SignatureException(
                    "error building signature, invalid key " + HASH_ALGORITHM);
                 }
    }

    public static String toHexString(byte[] bytes) {  
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(bytes.length * 2);  

            Formatter formatter = new Formatter(sb);  
            for (byte b : bytes) {  
                formatter.format("%02x", b);  
            }  

            return sb.toString();  
        }
```